# why some pages of a website are mentioned in the sitemap but not linked anywhere on the website not even mentioned in the header and footer?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

[image]

So I found these pages on the sitemap but I cannot see these pages on the website in the header or footer section. How come the user will interact with this page?

Comment: Shouldn't you know the answer as to why your website is structured the way it is?  I don't see how anybody here can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how and when the sitemap was generated. CMS can put private pages into sitemaps if you don't filter out post status. If you make a sitemap based on a crawl it would matter if they were orphanned or unlinked pages.

Even sitemaps have 404 errors.

All that said, those are live pages, and probably should be there.

Answer (score 0):

These are Location pages designed to be accessed via search engine results. Whilst they are not normally prominently accessible via header and footer menus due to large number of these types of pages, they are generally internally linked via the HTML sitemap.